# Is my identity exposed when publishing my public key or encrypting with PGP?

Tags: encryption, public-key, pgp

Let's say I create my PGP keys with my appropriate name and email address.

1. Will these personal information be exposed if I publish my public key?
2. When I encrypt a message for sending it to my communication partner, if someone intercepts this encrypted message, will he or she get to know about my personal information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, your public key includes your UIDs. It may be possible to delete all before exporting though - for sure you could copy the key, add an "anonymous" UID and delete all others.
2. As long as you're not signing the message, nobody will know who sent the message (but have a look at the mail or other headers!).

Comment: How can I delete UID of my public key? And by "have a look at the mail or other headers", do you mean if I send the encrypted text via my regular email address?

Comment: I have asked my first question [here](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9403/how-can-i-remove-my-personal-data-from-my-pgp-public-key).

Comment: I answered the new question. Yes, I was talking about email headers which are not encrypted when using OpenPGP.